# How to exclude a site from search result source but keep its subsites in search results?

Tags: query, sharepoint-search

How to exclude a site from search result source but keep its subsites in search results?
I have a site collection in which i used to make team sites and project sites.
In search results i want that all the subsites in that site collection should appear but that site collection needs to be excluded from search results. I tried the query as

```
-Path:siteurl
```

But this query excludes all the subsites of that site collection. Please help?

Comment: Are you on-prem or SPO? Although I would not recommend having a "secure root site" with public sites below it, have you tried just adding security to the root and opening up the sub sites?

Comment: I'm on on-prem currently. Actually i have created a site and named it to "teamsite" and in that site i allow users to create sites. Also i want to show the users all the teamsites created in a page so i created a result source for that. But that root site ("teamsite") is coming in results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really late answer, I know! But in my case this query string worked:

contentclass:STS_Web path:http://sitecolname/* Site<>{Site.URL}

First statement gives you only webs in your result, path parameter searches for all webs and subwebs in the defined path. The last statement excludes the current site from your results. And there you have it.
Off course this only works while using the search result web part on the current site collection.

You could also use "SiteTitle<>[SiteColName]" but that really requires a static site collection name that does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be an option just to exclude the lists on the root site from search (list settings - > advanced settings)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i got that hint from excluding lists from search and found that if i want to exclude a site then i need to go to `Site Settings > Search > Search and offline availability and settings`, then setting the "Allow this site to appear in search results?" option to "No".